# How to select rows based on condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following is the code snippet. 
Just design purpose I have added.

Here The user will be assigned multiple group.

So I want to select the person details alone.

**Here Person id 103** have two different persmission for the same **Product**.
But the higher permission only be selected for the person.
But if he is not assinged to multiple group, the default permission should be selected.

**Sample data**

```html
ProdId PersonId GroupId Permission

10103 78         55          15 
10103 99         33     15
10103 100         33     0
10103 103         33     15
10103 103         40     0
10103 112         33     15
```

**Result data should be**

```html
ProdId PersonId Permission

    10103 78         15 
    10103 99         15
    10103 100         0
    10103 103         15
    10103 112         15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.prodid,t.personID ORDER BY t.permission DESC) as rnk
    FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

I assumed you want the highest number on `permission` by your example? If not, change the `ORDER BY` clause to what you want.

Right now it will select all columns, specify the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, try the below query..

```
select * from (
select ProdID, PersonID, Permission, row_number() over (partition by PersonID order by Permission Desc) as column1 from table1)
where column1 = 1;
```